# Using wildcard in remote path using Paramiko's SFTPClient

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I want to copy the file from remote server to local.

```
import paramiko
paramiko.util.log_to_file('/tmp/paramiko.log')

# open transport
username = "user"
host="example.com"
port = 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.start_client()
private_key_file = "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa"
agent = paramiko.Agent()
key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(private_key_file)
transport.auth_publickey(username, key)

# get sftp client
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
source = "/home/user/user_1.csv"
target = "/home/local/local_sftp.txt"
sftp.get(x[0], x[1])
```

Above code is working fine but I want to use `source = "/home/user/user_*.csv"` but this wildcard is not evaluated.
Can someone please help me fix this problem.

I found [one solution for `SCPClient`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926123/using-wildcards-in-file-names-using-pythons-scpclient-library) but not able to fix the problem for `SFTPClient`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paramiko `SFTPClient` does not support wildcards.

So you have to list files in a remote folder yourself and filter them to those you want to download:

```
import re
```

```
remote_path = "/home/user"
local_path = "/home/local"

files = sftp.listdir(remote_path)

for filename in files:
    if re.match("^user_.*\\.csv$", filename):
        print(filename)
        sftp.get(remote_path + "/" + filename, local_path + "/" + filename)
```

Or use the `fnmatch` module. See [List files on SFTP server matching wildcard in Python using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49381899/850848).

Answer (score 3):

After retrieving the list of files, [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) is usually better than regex expression for this job:

```
import fnmatch
for name in sftp.listdir(remote_path):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, "user_*.csv"):
        print(name)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still, it failed, Filename is like `Opt_adv048-2020.12.23.14.05.51.csv.pgp` . I tried pattern as `Opt_adv048-*.csv.pgp`

Answer (score 0):

Just an Easy soloution if you the SFTPServer deployed on the *nix like systems, use `execute` method like this:

```
conn.execute("ls dir/*.csv")
```

Comment: That assumes you have a shell access to the server and that it's a Linux server. While this question is about SFTP.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl SFTP is the abbreviation of SSH File Transfer Protocol, so basically if you have SFTP you have a Linux server, maybe you mean FTPS!

Comment: Absolutely not. There are SFTP servers for all systems, not only for Linux. And even on Linux, you can have an SFTP access without a shell access.

Comment: Yup but in actual question its obvious he is using linux and linux is not vital! Using shell and bash is important

Comment: But we do not know if OP has a shell access. I'm not saying that your answer is not useful. But the question is about [tag:sftp]. Your answer does not use SFTP, but shell. So it should say it, so it's clear that not everyone will be able to use your solution