# Paramiko scp copy from remote machine regular expression

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko, scp

Is there way i can copy remote files that ends with name "output" using paramiko scp.

I have below code, which copies only if i provide full path or exact file name

Below is code

```
 import paramiko
 import os
 from paramiko import SSHClient
 from scp import SCPClient


def createSSHClient(self, server):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(server, self.port, self.user, self.password)
    return client

  def get_copy(self, hostname, dst):
    ssh = self.createSSHClient(hostname)
    scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
    scp.get(dst)
    scp.close()
```

What am trying is

```
     get_copy(1.1.1.1, "*output")
```

I am getting file not found Error

Comment: Perhaps little more detail about what you want to achieve would be great. From what I understand, paramiko can run `ls ${dst} -p | grep -v /` to get filenames, and iterate over it with `if name.endswith('output'): ...`, and so on

Comment: Hi Chris, Sorry my question is confusing. I corrected in post so others will understand clearly

Comment: See also [Using wildcards in file names using Python's SCPClient library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47926123/850848).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe need to use ssh to get list first, then scp them one by one.

Something like follows, just FYI.

```
def get_copy(self, hostname, dst):
    ssh = createSSHClient(hostname)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls /home/username/*output')
    result = stdout.read().split()

    scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
    for per_result in result:
        scp.get(per_result)
    scp.close()
    ssh.close()
```

Comment: While this works, you can also filter the files server-side, what is more efficient. See [Using wildcards in file names using Python's SCPClient library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47926123/850848). Of course, only when the shell wildcards work for your  filtering needs.

Answer (score 2):

There are two more ways which I found useful in this context.

1) You may also do it without using SCPClient, but just Paramiko itself. Like -

```
def get_copy(self, hostname, dst):
    ssh = createSSHClient(hostname)
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
    serverfilelist = sftp.listdir(remote_path)
    for f in serverfilelist:
            if re.search("*output", f):
                sftp.get(os.path.join(remote_path, f), local_path)

    ssh.close()
```

2) If you want to use SCPClient to SCP files using regex(wildcards), [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926123/using-wildcards-in-file-names-using-pythons-scpclient-library) link will 
   be helpful, I think.